# Парсинг картинок с сайта и вставка их относительных ссылок в txt документ

Tags: java

Есть задача спарсить с сайта картинки и вставить их в тоже самое место, где они были на сайте. Информация с сайта записывается в txt документ. Есть ли возможность скачать картинки на свой компьютер, поименовать их по порядку и по порядку вставить в нужные места в документе?
Парсер пишу на Java

```
<div class="question" id="svoisk17.1-1">

<p>
    <strong class="Question"><a href="/question/svoisk17.1/1">Вопрос 1</a>:</strong> <br/><img src="https://db.chgk.info/images/db/20170243.jpg"><br/>
<br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Перед вами АЛЬФА. Назовите ее тремя словами, начинающимися на одну и
ту же букву.        </p>
 <div class='collapsible collapsed'>
 <div class="collapse-processed"><a href="#">...</a></div>
  <p>
    <strong class="Answer">Ответ:</strong> Фаланга Франсиско Франко.    </p>
<p>
    <strong class="PassCriteria">Зачёт:</strong> Фотография фаланги Франко.    </p>
<p>
    <strong class="Comments">Комментарий:</strong> Мы раздали вам в буквальном смысле фалангу (в смысле, часть пальца)
испанского каудильо. Испанская Фаланга (исп. Falange Espa&ntilde;ola) &mdash;
ультраправая политическая партия в Испании, при тоталитарном режиме
Франко &mdash; правящая и единственная законная партия в стране.    </p>
<p>
    <strong class="Sources">Источник(и):</strong> <br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1. http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Фаланга_(анатомия)
<br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;2. http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Франко,_Франсиско
<br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;3. https://topwar.ru/14703-generalissimus-fransisko-franko-istoriya-zhizni.html    </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Для парсинга HTML лучше взять [JSoup](https://jsoup.org/)
А дальше примерно как в примере на главной странице

```
String domainName = "http://www.youaddress.com";
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(domainName).get();
Elements images = doc.select("img");
int fileIdx = 0;
for (Element image : images) {
    log("%s\n", image.attr("src"));
    InputStream in = new URL(domainName + image.attr("src")).openStream();
    Files.copy(in, "image-" + idx + ".jpg", StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    fileIdx++;
}
```